# Unstable wifi connection leads to non-responding desktop and programs

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, iwlwifi

I'm new to Ubuntu and running it in Version 16.04.4 LTS on a Thinkpad L560. Currently I experience issues with my wifi connection: Sometimes the connection drops (although the status bar shows that I am connected) and I experience a high paket loss when I ping a server. At the same time, any action I perform with the desktop is not executed until I disable the wifi. With ethernet I have no problem, so I guess it is an issue with my wifi drivers.

My wireless chipset is the Intel Wireless 8260, `sudo lshw -C network` says the driver version is 4.13.0-41-generic with firmware version 31.560484.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to restart your wifi network? You can do it with

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: It worked, but not for long. Problem remains, and at the time it occurs I can only deactivate wifi in the status bar, any console input is delayed until then. After that I can activate wifi again and it works properly for some time.

Comment: so your wifi didn't stay connected when you restart it? have you try the command above in the terminal, or you just restart the wifi with the graphic tools of ubuntu?